# How do I add a namespace attribute to an element in JAXB when marshalling?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I'm working with eBay's LMS (Large Merchant Services) and kept running into the error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXException:
>   SimpleDeserializer encountered a child
>   element, which is NOT expected, in
>   something it was trying to
>   deserialize.

After *a lot* of trial and error I traced the problem down. It turns out this works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BulkDataExchangeRequests xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Header>
    <Version>583</Version>
    <SiteID>0</SiteID>
  </Header>
  <AddFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
```

While this (what I've been sending) doesn't:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BulkDataExchangeRequests xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Header>
    <Version>583</Version>
    <SiteID>0</SiteID>
  </Header>
  <AddFixedPriceItemRequest>
```

The difference is the XML namespace attribute on the `AddFixedPriceItemRequest`. All of my XML is currently being marshalled via JAXB and I'm not sure what is the best way to go about adding a second xmlns attribute to a different element in my file.

So that's the question. How do I add an xmlns attribute to another element in JAXB?

```
package ebay.apis.eblbasecomponents;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AddFixedPriceItemRequestType", propOrder = {
    "item"
})
public class AddFixedPriceItemRequestType
    extends AbstractRequestType
{

    @XmlElement(name = "Item")
    protected ItemType item;

    public ItemType getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(ItemType value) {
        this.item = value;
    }
}
```

Added class definition by request.

Edited the above class like so to no effect:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents",
name = "AddFixedPriceItemRequestType", propOrder = {
    "item"
})
public class AddFixedPriceItemRequestType
```

Here is a snippet of the `BulkDataExchangeRequestsType` class. I tried throwing a `namespace="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"` into the `@XmlElement` for `AddFixedPriceItemRequest` but it didn't do anything.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BulkDataExchangeRequestsType", propOrder = {
    "header",
    "addFixedPriceItemRequest"
})
public class BulkDataExchangeRequestsType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Header")
    protected MerchantDataRequestHeaderType header;
    @XmlElement(name = "AddFixedPriceItemRequest")
    protected List<AddFixedPriceItemRequestType> addFixedPriceItemRequest;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "generated via JAXB"? Could you add a definition of your AddFixedPriceItemRequest class

Comment: I'm using marshalling via JAXB to generate the XML. I can't see any specific tag that adds the xmlns attribute to the BulkDataExchangeRequestsType class. I added the AddFixedPriceItemRequestType class definition to the question.

Comment: Why not generate aginst the schema specified in the WSDL?
http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/bulk-data-exchange/latest/BulkDataExchangeService.wsdl

Comment: did you tried to specify namespace as attribute value in @XmlType as in my answer?

Comment: @Martin OConnor You're referring to the BulkDataExchange service, but the file in question is headed towards the FileTransfer service. The classes that I am using are all generated off of the Merchant API since eBay has said they don't have an exact schema for the FileTransfer service. I modified the MerchantData.xsd to generate what I have so far.

Comment: @Mykola Golubyev - I did try a type annotation but it didn't seemt o do anything (see above for what I added).

Comment: @Mykola Golubyev - I also tried modifying the @XmlElement where AddFixedPriceItemRequest is defined on BulkDataExchangeRequestsType, again to no affect.

Comment: Ok. Let's do this. You will add extra code which you use JAXB to generate xml and tomorrow (if it still won't be solved) I will write my own JAXB generation (Now I don't have access to my IDE).

Comment: Can you show the BulkDataExchangeRequests class with the AddFixedPriceItemRequestType property?

Comment: Done. I added it to the question as UPDATE 3. Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried to add namespace to the @XmlElement(name = "AddFixedPriceItemRequest") protected List<AddFixedPriceItemRequestType> addFixedPriceItemRequest;

Comment: Yes, I explicitly mentioned that in the small paragraph preceding the code in Update 3. It didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your XML fragments are semantically identical. The `xmlns` attribute on the `AddFixedPriceItemRequest` element is redundant, since it implicitly inherits the namespace of its parent element. JAXB knows this, and so doesn't bother adding the namespace to `AddFixedPriceItemRequest` - it's just not necessary.

If the ebay server is only working when the `AddFixedPriceItemRequest` `xmlns` is present, then it's broken, and is making demands on the input over and above those required by XML and by the schema. If this is indeed the case (which is hard to believe, but possible), then using a Java XML document model like JAXB is going to be a struggle, since that will assume XML is XML is XML. Low-level farting about with which elements get the `xmlns` declarations is not exposed to the API, since it shouldn't be needed.

None of which is helping you. My approach would be to marshal the JAXB model to a DOM object (using a `DOMResult` passed to the `Marshaller`), and then see if you can do some manual tweaking of the DOM to force the `xmlns` into the document at the appropriate places. You can then serialize that DOM to XML and send that.

You shouldn't have to do this, and I suspect you may be doing something else wrong somewhere; this is more likely than the ebay web service being broken like this.

---

edit: here's another suggestion, a bit less awful than the JAXB-to-DOM-to-XML solution. If your request XML is reasonable static in structure, with only the numeric/string values changing, then define it as a String template, then replace the values at runtime, and send that. You can then interpret the results using JAXB. I've done this in the oast with web services thyat required very exact namespace prefixes, when persuading the java XML libraries to conform to that was unreasonably hard.

Comment: You're right, it makes no sense at all, however, I've tested it - sending the exact same file (their LMS service requires you to upload a file that they then process when they get around to it basically) except for that one change of an extra xmlns. Without it, the service returns "Failed" every time. When it is there it doesn't have that problem. I guess I was hoping there was an easier way - dragging it through DOM seems really cumbersome but I'm getting the feeling any solution will be a beast at this point.

Comment: Unfortunately that probably won't work as it is rather dynamic in how it creates its content. Good thought though is that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use class annotation

```
@XmlType(namespace="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents")
```

or

```
@XmlElement(namespace="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents")
```

property annotation if you only want to specify namespace only in some certain cases

Comment: this does not work, I am encountering the same problem as the poster

Answer (score 4):

Check if the fields in a generated classed are missing the `@XmlElement` annotation and if present are they missing the namespace attribute. These two must be present in order to get the namespace prefix against every element in your marshaled xml.