# Adding namespace on nested element with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JAXB marshalling XMPP stanzas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720501/jaxb-marshalling-xmpp-stanzas)

I have done some search here on stackoverflow and haven't really found the answer for what I need.

I'm having some trouble trying to manipulate namespaces using JAXB. Let's get to it.

I need an XML in the following format

```
<root xmlns="http://namespace/root">

    <item xmlns="http://namespace/item">
        <id>1</id>
        <name>First</name>
    </item>

    <item xmlns="http://namespace/item">
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Second</name>
    </item>
</root>
```

As you can see, I basically need to replicate the namespaces on **every** tag. When I try to create this using JAXB, I get the following XML output:

```
<root xmlns="http://namespace/root"
      xmlns:ns2="http://namespace/item">

    <ns2:item>
        <ns2:id>1</ns:id>
        <ns2:name>First</ns2:name>
    </ns2:item>

    <ns2:item>
        <ns2:id>2</ns:id>
        <ns2:name>Second</ns2:name>
    </ns2:item>
</root>
```

It obviously makes sense that it is generated like that, it uses the prefix so there shouldn't be any issue here,

but the consumer I send this XML to demands that it is in that format, in which I have to replicate the namespace for each and every item on the file.

Does anybody know how to do that? I thought of a String template, but since it is all already done with JAXB, I wondered if there wasn't any easier way to do this.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: as Blaise said it really was the same exact question that I had, I'm sorry I posted a new one but I didn't find it while seraching through stackoverflow.

Comment: There are similar questions answered on StackOverflow already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034515/jaxb-generate-xml-with-namespace-for-each-element , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751048/how-do-i-add-a-namespace-attribute-to-an-element-in-jaxb-when-marshalling
Maybe this will help you.